# PHP Create Procedure

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli

I try to create a stored procedure through php mysqli. I create another stored procedures and I didn´t have problems. This code:

```
$link = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "Question");
$link -> multi_query("DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS FacturaTerminarFactura;
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `FacturaTerminarFactura`(IN 
    id_factura INT(40), Total_factura DOUBLE, Total_IVA DOUBLE)
    BEGIN
    UPDATE `tb_factura`
        SET
        `tb_factura`.`intId_factura_resolucion_dian` = (SELECT
            MAX(`tb_resolucion_dian`.`intFactura_Actual`) FROM `tb_resolucion_dian`
            WHERE `tb_resolucion_dian`.`intEstado` = 1 LIMIT 1),
            `tb_factura`.`dblTotal_factura` = Total_factura,
            `tb_factura`.`dblIva` = Total_IVA
        WHERE `tb_factura`.`intid_factura` = id_factura;
   UPDATE `tb_resolucion_dian`
        SET `tb_resolucion_dian`.`intFactura_Actual` = 
            tb_resolucion_dian`.`intFactura_Actual` + 1
        WHERE `tb_resolucion_dian`.`intEstado` = 1;
   SELECT `tb_factura`.`intId_factura_resolucion_dian` AS ID
       FROM `tb_factura`
       WHERE `tb_factura`.`intid_factura` = id_factura;
END;");
$log  = "";
if ($mysqli -> warning_count) {
     if ($result = $link -> query("SHOW WARNINGS;")) {
         $row = $result -> fetch_row();
         $log .= $row[0]."-".$row[1]."-".$row[2]."\n";
         $result -> close();
     }
}
```

This is the error

```
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
server version for the right syntax to use near '`.`intFactura_Actual` 1 WHERE 
`tb_resolucion_dian`.`intEstado` = 1; ' at line 14
```

I see that the '+' is the problem, but I don't know how I can resolve.

Thanks and excuse me for my English.

Comment: What does "resolucion_dian" translate to? What is the data type?

Comment: tb_resolucion_dian is a table, but the problem is the '+' is cleared when I run the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo Here:

```
tb_resolucion_dian`.`intFactura_Actual` + 1
```

You're missing the backtick before `tb_resolucion_dian`

Also, according to [mysql docs for UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) you don't need to name the table name in the SET clause. The example given was UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1; where you have UPDATE t1 SET t1.col1 = t1.col1 + 1, which might also cause issues.

An alternative to UPDATE is [INSERT INTO ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html).

Comment: Are you sure that intFactura_Actual is an integer type in the datanase?

Comment: Yes, intFactura_Actual is an integer type

Comment: The problem was in PHP beacause, it was clearing the '+' in the sending to the control, I replaced '+' with '&#43;' and problem resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

simple fix try this

```
`intFactura_Actual` + 1
```

TO

```
`intFactura_Actual` = `intFactura_Actual` + 1
```

Thanks for comments I see i did not read the code right (Looks so weird here)
there is a spelling mistake in the code just like the other guy said.

Comment: If you look at the full context, he does do this.UPDATE `tb_resolucion_dian`
        SET `tb_resolucion_dian`.`intFactura_Actual` = 
            tb_resolucion_dian`.`intFactura_Actual` + 1